# Layout Interface Builder constraints issue since Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift2

Since I have updated my Swift project to Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8 (release version) I can't get my Interface done anymore:

[image]

I'm setting all the constraints perfectly. Everything works fine. I reopen Xcode the next day and all my Views look like this.

Also I'm getting tons of warnings:

[image]

If I click on `Update Frame`, the warning disappears and the View looks normal again. But as soon as I restart Xcode (or sometimes even just build the project) it's undone again...

[image]

**Important**: All the Views look PERFECT and as wanted inside any devices, but it's really hard to keep the overview.

I have spent a whole night replacing all the elements of my current project. Everything was fine without any warnings. The next day, the warnings were back and I had changed literally nothing. How do I get rid of this? Help is very much appreciated.

[image]

I can "update the frame", everything looks good again. After a couple of builds or at the very latest after re-opening Xcode, it looks like this again.

Latest example: Extreme simple screen. UIViewController. UINavigationBar. UITableView. No segues. One Prototype Cell.

[image]

Set all the Constraints perfectly last night. Reopened Xcode. Found this.

**Edit**:

The suggested work-around to switch desired controller's simulated size to freeform in inspector and then update frames is just a temporary solution.

As soon as I re-open Xcode, all the warnings are back again. I can change the value to fixed then, all the elements "pop back" to their desired position and the warnings disappear -> reopen Xcode and all the warnings are back and the controller's elements are all in a tumble again.

[image]

Also the suggestion to change the storyboard file type to 7.x didn't have any effect. I pressed 7.x, it asked me, if I wanted to change. I pressed OK. Loaded. I opened the main.storyboard and it asked me in what device I wanted to open the storyboard on. Xcode 8.0 was re-selected then.

[image]

Comment: It happens every time after you restart the Xcode?

Comment: it happens sometimes even without restart. keep coding... keep running apps. go to storyboard a couple of minutes or hours later and all the warnings are back

Comment: but yes. a restart is a guarantee to bring the warnings back

Comment: but sometimes just a build is enough

Comment: I had the same problem with some of my views. Do you use view containers by any chance? For me, setting the contained view controller's simulated content size to 'Freeform' fixed the issue (at least somewhat, I still have other problems with views being the wrong size in the rendering).

Comment: I'm using View Containers in my project, yes. But I have this problem on Views without View Containers as well

Comment: @David see the latest edit/picture

Comment: Couple thoughts. 1) Do you use some Xcode extension (e.g. I wonder, what is “cya” icon in your screenshots?)? 2) I’ve never seen an issue you described, but I had hard times with Autolayout being unable satisfy the constraints without setting a placeholder intrinsic content size for some views (in IB).

Comment: Dude this has been 3 Swift evolutions and 3 Xcode release cycles ago! xD This issue is not relevant at all anymore @YevhenDubinin

Comment: @DavidSeek lol. I just woke up at that time...doh. Didn’t notice that was about Xcode 8 ;) Nice to know that issue is a thing of a past now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm working on a large project with multiple storyboards and lots of viewcontrollers. Had same issues on most of them. And figured it is happening because Xcode now supports constraints with decimal values.

Here is the fix worked for all of my UITableViews and UICollectionViews:

1) Remove only one of the "Height equals: xx" constraint from one of your views inside the cell.
2) Update all frames.
3) Select the view you removed constraint from.
4) Click to add new constraint button. Now it should be showing a new height, probably with a decimal value.
5) Add height constraint without changing the value inside the box.

Your problem should be fixed for that cell now. Repeat this steps for all cells that are broken. Hope this solution works for you as well. Good luck!

Comment: will try it later today. hope it works, but i have a good feeling, if it worked for you

Comment: unfortunately it seems not to help. if i select a cell and, as you said, delete one of the height constraints, just this one height contraint is deleted. i set it back and it will get back (not with decimal). once i reopen xcode, the problems are back again. also, all the other elements within that cell are still broken

Comment: but i'll keep trying with your suggestion and in 2 hours i'm able to upvote again. you'll get your upvote at the very least for your effort!

Comment: @DavidSeek if you can share a simple example storyboard with me which has the same problem, I can try to help you with it.

Comment: I will try to create one or try to export mine!

Comment: this is part of one of my storyboards. the assets are missing, of course, but you'll see some of the provided issues

Comment: Wow this is one big storyboard, for the sake of usability I recommend you to split this storyboard to multiple storyboards, believe me you will be happier in the future.  
And when we come back to your problem, since I didn't have much time, I only fixed 2 of your cells but the fix is same for all the others. And I fixed them with the steps in my original answer. For example;  
In your "Profile as user tweet tablevc scene" in "djProfile cell",  
1) Remove height constraint of "Bg View"  
2) Update all frames
3) Select "Bg View", add constraint and add height const. with the value in box.

Comment: In "New user tweet tablevc scene"
1) Remove height constraint from "Message text view",  
2) Update all frames
3) Select "Message text view" and add height constraint without changing value in the box.

And here is the fixed version if you want to check out:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqj0y1r2s3hzyc8/Testfinal.storyboard?dl=0

Comment: thank you for your effort. i'll check it out within the next hours. also, this is not nearly half of my storyboard. deleted plenty of screen for the test preview. but i'll try your suggestion and split the storyboard. might be useful to have a storyboard per scene/category. thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

Quick workaround: change the desired controllers' simulated size to freeform in inspector and then update frames. Looks like freeform controllers are not affected by these new Xcode 8 IB features :)

Comment: got it. well it does it. but whats the difference?

Comment: what is that feature for?

Comment: and simulated size, is that old from xcode7 or is that something new?

Comment: @DavidSeek looks like a bug to me now. you can also change the IB file type to 7.x like here: http://pasteboard.co/89PjTcnDL.png

Comment: okay your fix doesnt work for me. i change it to freeform. all the warnings are gone. i close and open xcode and all the warnings are back. if i switch to "fixed" again, the warnings are gone again, re-open xcode warnings are back.

Comment: @DavidSeek did you try to change the IB file type to 7.x?

Comment: did nothing at all. i pressed on 7.x, it asked me if I want to close it and reopen it with 7. pressed okay. loading. opened main.storyboard and it asked me, in what kind of device i want to open (like it did when i first opened it in xcode 8). and now the value xcode 8 is selected there again

Comment: well there's definitely a bug in the new xcode... hope they'll fix it in the next release

Comment: roll back to the previous version of Xcode http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3.1/Xcode_7.3.1.dmg

Comment: i hope so, too! i have mbp 15inch 2,5ghz and since i have updated to xcode 8, my performance halved. my project is pretty big and i have a couple of screens in the interface builder, but i wait 30 seconds for the interface builder to open... xcode 7 -> instantly...

Comment: roll back would be more trouble. i'm about to update all my code to swift 3

Comment: also i can't visit the page you're provided "unauthorized" even tho i'm logged into my dev account.. what ever. thank you very much mate